# Symfony - Error 404 in Routing

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

When I run the server and try the URLs I get error 404.

**src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml**

```
app_category:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/category.yml"
    prefix:   /category
```

**src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/category.yml**

```
category:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Category:index" }
category_new:
    path:     /new
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Category:new" }
```

**CategoryController**

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Category entities.
     *
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')->findAll();

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Category:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        ));
    }

    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Category();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Category:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you import 'src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml' in routing file in app/config?

Comment: There should be a `routing.yml` file inside `app/config` folder. Make sure you are importing your `AppBundle` routing file in `app/config/routing.yml` file.

Comment: check the configured route with the sf command `php app/console router:debug`

Comment: are you rewriting app.php/app_dev.php ?

Comment: Could you paste `routing.yml` file? (`app/config/routing.yml`)

Comment: Maybe `php app/console cache:clear` ? is this working if you just use /new ?